# Get download data from edge://downloads/all in the console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, console, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to get download data to test from Edge browser in the console, but I am having trouble figuring out how. For example, in Chrome, if you go to the downloads page you can open up the console and type in `document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList').items.filter(e => e.state === 'COMPLETE')` you should see a list with a bunch of json data about each download, such as filePath, url, state of download, etc.

Does anyone know how I can achieve the same thing in Edge? Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I compared the html source of Chrome download page and Edge download page. I find that they're totally different.

The download page in Chrome uses [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) and it defines [Custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) in the page. The download information you get is stored in the custom elements' properties so that you can get them using JavaScript.

[image]

But the download page in Edge just uses simple html and nested `<div>`. If you investigate the html code, you'll find that all the download information you can get is what shown on the page. And if we use `querySelector()` we can only get the HTMLCollection and it's hard to extract the download information.

[image]

In a conclusion, we can't achieve the same thing in Edge. If you need this feature in Edge, I suggest you provide feedback to Edge team about this issue by pressing `Alt + Shift + I` in Edge.